# regex to match only local CSS files

Tags: javascript, regex, html-parsing

I need to select local stylesheets from an HTML string in JavaScript. How can I turn the following into a regex?

```
(file.indexOf('<link rel="stylesheet"') === 0) && (file.indexOf('href="http') === -1)
```

Comment: Is this what you are trying to match?

Comment: Why do you want a regex for this? There are more reliable ways to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't parse HTML with regex!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2057919) HTML is not a regular language, and you will get much better results with a parser. For example, what if the `rel` attribute comes after the `href` attribute? That's valid HTML syntax, but not a scenario you are currently trying to handle. This could cause problems.

But if you insist, you could do this:

```
/<link (?=[^>]*rel=\s*['"]stylesheet['"])(?![^>]*href=\s*['"]http)[^>]*>/i
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kA7dU0/3)

Edit 1: handle either order of attributes

Edit 2: handle single or double quotes, case insensitivity, and spacing

Comment: Should use case insensitivity too, though this can fail because of single (or no) quotes.

Comment: var my_string = (document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).innerHTML;
(my_string.match(/<link (?=[^>]*rel="stylesheet")(?![^>]*href="http)[^>]*>/i) == (my_string.indexOf('<link rel="stylesheet"') === 0) && (my_string.indexOf('href="http') === -1))?true:false;

returns false ...

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos I'm not really sure what you're saying. Are you saying the regex doesn't produce the same results as the original logic? If so, the test case (the HTML for the `<link>` in question) would be more useful than the JS code you posted.

Comment: I agree, i think the question is wrong... The first .indexOf shoulden't be >=0 ?